# JavaScript sort comparator function

Tags: javascript

Basically I want to build a function which sorts objects in an array by one of the object's properties/member variables. I am preeeety sure that the comparator function is where the error is hidden, but I am not 100% sure.

The output I should get after the sort function is called is `1,2,3`. I get `1,3,2` which means that it is unchanged

This is the entire js code (with some comments):

```
var arr = [];
//object definition and creation
var main = document.getElementById("main");
var task = {
    name: "",
    priority: 0
};

//first
var one = Object.create(task);
one.priority = 1;
//secondd
var two = Object.create(task)
two.priority = 3;
//last
var three = Object.create(task);
three.priority = 2;

//append
arr.push(one);
arr.push(two);
arr.push(three);

//sort function
function sortT() {
    arr.sort(compareFN);
}

//comperator function
function compareFN() {
    return task.priority < task.priority;
}

function print() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        console.log(arr[i].priority);   
    }
}

//execution of the program
print();
sortT();
print();
```

EDIT: The solution is the following - As stated, the comparator function really was the problem, the correct way to write it is the following:

```
function compareFN(taskA, taskB) {
   return taskA.priority < taskB.priority;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compare function needs two arguments: the first and the second element it should compare.
So your compareFN should look like this:

```
function compareFN(taskA, taskB) {
   return taskA.priority - taskB.priority;
}
```

Edit: [As NPE said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17382112/1453095), it is supposed to perform a [three-way comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), so a simple `a < b` is not so a great idea here.

Answer (score 9):

There are multiple problems with your comparator:

1. It refers to the global `task` object instead of the objects being compared.
2. It compares the object to itself.
3. It is supposed to perform a [three-way comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-way_comparison).

Try:

```
var compareFN = function(a, b) {
    return a.priority - b.priority;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the signature of you compare function to include the two tasks.

For ascending order (normally what you want) you need to do b < a, a < b will do descending order

```
//comperator function
function compareFN(a, b) {
    return b.priority < a.priority;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The comparator function returns a negative value, zero or a positive value. Those three comprise what is called here the three-way comparison.
So:
'''
 function cmp((a, b) => {
     // ascending
     return a - b
}
'''
For descending return b - a